# Graph API Teams Get chatMessageHostedContent not able to get existing images

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to migrate teams channel messages to another channel (or make backup of it), but I'm unable to get images embedded within the message.

I have successfully listed messages, parsed their `body.content` and extracted valid URI for retrieval of the image.

As stated in [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessagehostedcontent-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) for GET requests finishing with ".../$value" Graph API should return a binary image file, but I'm getting a 200 OK with payload JSON containing only key-value pair of the resource ID I have sent within a request instead of the image. No error returned.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Mea culpa!
I have been using PowerShell and did not properly escape $ (dollar sign) in front of the ".../$value". Using ' instead of " resolved the issue, and now I'm receiving the image files.